# Expires headers do not work

Tags: .htaccess, caching

I tried a couple of approaches to get images and other resources to have an expiration date, but none seem to work accourding to http://www.webpagetest.org/

I also installed W3 plugin, still the tool reports the images do not have expires headers set.

I also included the following code in my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A300
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A3600
ExpiresByType text/css A3600
ExpiresByType image/gif A3600
ExpiresByType image/png A3600
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A3600
ExpiresByType text/plain A300
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A3600
ExpiresByType video/x-flv A3600
ExpiresByType application/pdf A3600
ExpiresByType text/html A300
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This seems to be a common problem, and I have seen many questions about this, but couldn't find an answer.

Is the problem in the testing tool or on my server? How can I find out?

Comment: Why do you think this is a WordPress question?

Comment: becasuse im using wordpress and thought it maybe wordpress specif problem. perhaps this belongs on stackoverflow.

Comment: The .htaccess is read and executed long before WordPress has even started. Will move it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same kind of problem. It seems (some) validators, like YSlow, don't succeed until the expires dates are on value `31536000`.

Here's a full W3 Total Cache htaccess: http://pastebin.com/wegK3jD6.
It worked for me, you might as well give it a shot.

**Note that the pastebin doesn't contain the WordPress htaccess content**

Comment: tried it with 31536000 but still the same, also tried the code from your paste bin and its the same

Comment: You could try searching in the [webpagetest docs](https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/) for rules and limitations?

Comment: thx ill try that. So basically you are saying the test is wrong, and the htaccess works? Is there a way to find out if there isnt anything wrong with my server?

Comment: I don't want to say that the sets is wrong since I don't have any experience with it. You could, however, test your page with YSlow and PageSpeed Insights for Chrome to compare the different results.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for me was enable expires module.

```
a2enmod expires
systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer by: *Southparkfan* in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-setup-expire-headers-on-apache

So this code will work in apache server conf

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 15 days"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
    ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 1 months"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 months"

    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

We were trying to get a wrong result. i was searching for a solution too but what i found after reading the GTMetrix test result with those (expire header)  code and without them:

- the expire header code is working but only with internal files.
- the expire header code will not work with external files(from other websites like google analytics js ...).
- the test result will show you only the external files.
- if you remove those lines of codes the result will be worst, and it will result in more files doesn't have an expired age.